# Sketch (45) > 2 symbols with different height, in artboard not adjusting height

Tags: sketch-app, symbols

Currently I'm working on a large project with many symbols. When I switch between symbols in the artboard they won't adjust the height of the selected symbol.

Example:

I have 2 symbols:

Symbol A) is 100 x 40 pixels
Symbol B) is 100 x 100 pixels

I added symbol A to the artboard, so it's a symbol of 100 x 40 pixels.
I change symbol A into symbol B via the dropdown option (right panel). Symbol B is being displayed but is still 100 x 40 pixels (instead of 100 x 100).

How can I auto adjust symbols to their native height or width when switching between them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no setting for doing this automatically. But if you right click the symbol and click on Set to original size. The symbol will jump to the correct height.